# h2xs: How to create directory structure

Tags: perl-module

I am using `h2xs` v. 1.23 to create `Perl` modules. But every time I use the command `h2xs -A -X -n Module::Foo` I get this directory structure: `Module-Foo/lib/Module/foo.pm`. That results in ugly single directories for all Modules.

My desired structure should be: Module/Foo/lib/Module/bar.pm so I can add a second module `h2xs -A -X -n Module::Bar` to get `Module/Bar/lib/Module/bar.pm`.

Does anybody know how to do this?
Thx.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried module-starter? try this command

`module-starter --module=Module::Foo,Module::Bar --author="ME" --email="me@me.com"`

You can add several modules by simply adding them under the module flag.